# Writing to the same file from two mappers

Tags: hadoop

In Hadoop MR (basically HDFS), is it possible to write to the same file from two mappers belonging to a single job in synchronous/serialized fashion?

Also writing to a single file from two mappers running in different jobs in a serialized fashion?

There are semaphores in other filesystems. What is the mechanism in HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no communication between the map tasks in Hadoop, so some sort of synchronization between them is not possible.
2. Files in HDFS may be written by a single writer, while many readers can read it.
3. I think [MapR](http://www.mapr.com/) allows multiple writers to the same file.

FYI, the file has to be appended at the end and modifications at any arbitrary offset are also not possible.

Just curious, what is the use case for multiple map tasks writing to a single file?

Answer (score 0):

Set the number or reducers = 1 (mapred.reduce.tasks=1)